# How to get slopes of data in pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get slopes of dataset in the dataframe (either using linear regression model or sk-learn model).

```
df1:
   A     B     C     D  
0  15    25    55    100
1  15.5  25.5  56    101
2  14.8  24.5  54.2  99.8
3  15.5  25.5  55.5  102
4  16    26    57    108
```

I want to get slopes of each dolumn ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') in the form of pd.Series. Can you help me on this? Thank you.

The output I want is something like below (I used just dummy numbers, not real slopes!):

```
slopes:
A  2.5
B  2.8
C  3.1
D  3.3
```

Comment: Just wondering, how did you get 2.5 as slope for column A ?

Comment: 2.5, 2.8, 3.1, 3.3 ...are not real slope. I just used dummy number. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: scipy has all the methods you need.

Comment: [scipy linear regression link to doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)

Comment: But to calculate slope for column A you need another column and like for others. What about that ?

Comment: If you're going to provide an output (and you should), then make it the expected output for the example given.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes Sacul is right. I want slopes of each column fitted with the index ([0,1,2,3,4]). My actual data is stock prices with time-series data. I just simplified it. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I believe this does it, it's a simple linear regression with `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

slopes = df.apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(df.index, x, 1)[0])

>>> slopes
A    0.20
B    0.20
C    0.35
D    1.70
```

And if you want to visualize the data and the fitted slopes:

```
for i in df.columns:
    plt.scatter(df.index, df[i], label=i)
    plt.plot(np.polyval(np.polyfit(df.index, df[i], 1), df.index))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sacul, Thanks. But I tried the way you showed for several times, it did not work. I don't know what went wrong....maybe some bugs in my data? ..I'm still reviewing. Thanks.

Comment: The error message says, "TypeError : ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'float'", 'occurred at index XLK').."

Comment: Oh, that's a different type of problem; you're trying to fit a float series with a date series. You should convert your index to a numeric range (for instance, number of days since the first day in your observation period, or something). For future problems, make sure that your example is similar to your actual data

Comment: Sacul, I've changed the index to numeric numbers just like the example I put above. (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). Now the error message says, " ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float' ", 'occurred at index A' ) ." What does this mean?

Comment: Try this: `df.index = list(map(float,df.index))`, and try the code again.

Comment: Sacul, Thanks a lot. I found some bugs in my raw data, fixed and re-ran your code (first one). It worked perfectly! Thank you!